# gcc compiling error, object initialization interpreted as function pointer?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

The following code:

```
class Angle {
protected:
   double rad;
   Angle(double r) : rad(r){}
};

class Radian : public Angle {
public:
   Radian(double rad) : Angle(rad){}
};

class Latitude : public Angle {
public:
   Latitude(const Angle&a) : Angle(a){}
   Latitude operator-(const Latitude &other){
      return Latitude(Radian(rad-other.rad));
   }
};

int main(){
   double d = 0.7;
   Latitude lat1(Radian(0.8));
   Latitude lat2(Radian(d*1));
   Latitude lat3(Radian(d));
   Latitude diff2 = lat1 - lat2;
   Latitude diff3 = lat1 - lat3;
   return 0;
}
```

gives compiler error:

```
$ g++ bug.cpp
bug.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
bug.cpp:26:26: error: no match for ‘operator-’ (operand types are ‘Latitude’ and ‘Latitude(Radian)’)
    Latitude diff3 = lat1 - lat3;
                          ^
bug.cpp:26:26: note: candidate is:
bug.cpp:15:13: note: Latitude Latitude::operator-(const Latitude&)
    Latitude operator-(const Latitude&l){
             ^
bug.cpp:15:13: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘Latitude(Radian)’ to ‘const Latitude&’
```

If I try to do `lat3 - lat3` it will give this error, indicating that it interprets `lat3` as a function pointer:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids using pointer to a function in subtraction [-fpermissive]
lat3 - lat3;
       ^
```

`lat2 - lat2` is ok.

So what is going on here? Why is lat2 and lat3 interpreted as different types? What exactly is meant by `Latitude(Radian)` in the error message?

Compiler output is from gcc 4.9.1, similar results are obtained with gcc versions 4.1 to 4.9. Platform is 64bit RHEL6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your line to:

```
Latitude lat3((Radian(d)));
```

The problem you run into is known as

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: Or use Latitude lat3 { Radian(d) };

Comment: Or change the line to Latitude lat3(Radian((double)d));